# Need an understanding of how to push code to a different branch in Bitbucket using Git Bash

Tags: git, bitbucket

So, I have been working on some code in a particular branch A. However, turns out, I have to push all those changes to a different branch B. Could someone explain how to go about that process? I have done the following so far:

```
git pull -> pulled all code in A
Made code changes to 5 files
git stash -> stashed all my changes in A
git checkout B -> checked out to B after stashing
git stash apply -> applying stashed code to B
```

I understand getting merge conflicts. But, is it possible to stash my changes in one branch, and apply them in the other? Also, how do I resolve the merge conflicts in this case?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you used tags [tag:git-bash] *and* [tag:visual-studio-code]. Note that `git-bash` is just a command line interpreter (`bash`) ported for use on Windows; it's not part of Git itself. Git needs an sh/bash-compatible command line interpreter, so Windows versions of Git tend to come *with* git-bash, but it's a completely separate thing.

Comment: Anyway, I'm answering from a command-line point of view.  I took out the [tag:angular] tag because Angular is irrelevant, but probably so are both the [tag:visual-studio-code] and [tag:git-bash] tags.

Comment: Thank you, will keep this in mind before adding tags.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you are doing. You have merge conflicts simply because some of the files you changed have also been changed on branch B (compared to A). They are part of the game. You can use `git mergetool` to help resolve them.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, was able to get my changes on B after resolving merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stash might be a little more work than necessary. I would suggest that you just add and commit in the usual way. Now rebase this commit onto the other branch. You might get conflicts; no problem, resolve them.